# How to create a scene file for ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

Inside the ARKit sample source code, I can see ".scn" [scene kit files]. 
I am wondering that how to create a new scene file? 
Let's say a coin scene?

Any website where I can download? or learn how to create one for my use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create one from scratch in Xcode’s “New File” dialog. It’s a resource type (in the same area as GPX files). Chris Language’s book on building SceneKit games has a very nice section on using the Xcode Scene editor, the best documentation I’ve seen on that tool.

You can also use NSSecureCoding and archive an SCNScene that you’ve created programmatically. See [SceneKit view is rendered backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575074/scenekit-view-is-rendered-backwards/44600129#44600129) for sample code.

Comment: Hey Hal, thank you so much for taking me forward. I have added a new scene file within the Xcode and then I am not sure how to take it further?

Comment: You’ll need to put it in your art.assets folder and load it by name. The Chris Language book is available online and covers this stuff thoroughly. You can also create a plain SceneKit Game (no ARKit) and mimic the structure of that template project, which includes the infamous ship.scn.

Comment: I’ll add that the Scene Editor has a learning curve similar to SketchUp or Blender. If you’re familiar with one of those tools, or with Maya, or if you have assets already in those formats, you’ll probably be happier converting your asset to .SCN format, rather than taking the time to get good at Scene Editor. Do this with Model I/O or by importing to the Scene Editor.

Comment: I think the book that @HalMueller is referencing is https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/3d-apple-games-by-tutorials, although there's also some nice general tutorials on SceneKit and getting started (by Chris) at https://www.raywenderlich.com/u/chrislanguage and http://dayoftheindie.com/tutorials/3d-games-graphics/tutorial-intro-arkit-scenekit/