# How to create .scn file which can be used as virtual object in iOS 11 using AR?

Tags: ios11, xcode9-beta, arkit

I downloaded ARKit demo provided by apple and i seen that there are .scn files which are used as virtual object in app, How can i create other virtual object file like same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a scene file for ARKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668122/how-to-create-a-scene-file-for-arkit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create realistic .scn files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814390/how-to-create-realistic-scn-files)

Answer (score 7):

In Xcode **File -> New -> file -> SceneKit Scene File** to create your blank scene file.

You can also drag and drop your **.dae** file into Xcode project and convert it into **.scn** directly by clicking **Editor -> Convert to Scenekit Scene File Format(.scn)**